# Scheme sorting vector by length

Tags: sorting, vector, scheme, depth-first-search

I have a dfs method will return me list of vectors, How can I sort the elements according to the length of the vector.

```
(define (dfs path) ;path store vector index, start from 0 
 (cond
 ((dfsStack' empty?)(newline))
  (else (set! currentPath (dfsStack' pop!))
      (findLast (car currentPath) 0)
      (checkUnvisited (cdr (vector-ref network lastNum)))

      (cond
        ((eq? lastName reach) ;reach point
         (duplicate path)          
         (dfs (+ path 1)) ;continue dfs to find next path         
         )
        ((and (not (eq? lastName reach))(eq? unvisited #t)) ;no more neighbours
         (dfs path)
         ) 
        ((and (not (eq? lastName reach))(eq? unvisited #f)) ;found the neighbours
         (pushStack lastNeighbours currentPath)
         (dfs path)
         )
        );//end cond
      )   
);//end cond
);//end dfs
```

Answer (score 1):

Same way as in your previous question [Scheme Vector using merge sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858177/scheme-vector-using-merge-sorting)

just replace `length` with `vector-length`.

Comment: (sort list-of-vectors compare-vectors)

where

    (define (compare-vectors vec1 vec2)
      <expression comparing the length of the two vectors>)